# Is it okay to have hyphens in brand/company name?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers, marketing, branding

My domain name is without hyphens, but I promote/market my brand/company name with hyphens in between (example: 'company-name'). Is it okay to have such difference? Or will it affect in any way to SEO or marketing or anything else?

Comment: This article is better than anything I could write on this subject: [Should I put a dash in my domain name?](https://news.gandi.net/en/2020/08/should-i-put-a-dash-in-my-domain-name/)

Comment: IME, in the UK, it's a pain telling people a domain name with a hyphen in. I switched to using domains and writing them in CamelCase when the word break might not be clear (which is handled transparently by browsers as domains are case-insensitive). You still end up saying "all one word". Having observed that 90%+ of people type the domain name in Google search telling people the domain name is probably only relevant to communicating your email address. Assuming Google Search knows where the word break is...

Answer (score 2):

You're all good, don't sweat this. Just refer to your brand name as you normally would on page and within your [NAP info](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/137433/122139). That's where search engines are really going to look to understand who you are.